# GapWorker with Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

When i scroll my recyclerview too fast i am getting the following crash

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:5659)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleView(RecyclerView.java:5603)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:277)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:324)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:337)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:344)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:370)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I had tried my every effort and get similar question on stackoverflow, but none of them were helpful like following links,

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199216/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-scrapped-or-attached-views-may-not-be-recycl)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693821/fragment-with-recyclerview-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-scrapped-or-att)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043559/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-scrapped-or-attached-views-may-not-be-recycl)

[Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477660/recyclerview-crashes-when-scrapped-or-attached-views-may-not-be-recycled)

[Link 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263355/scrapped-or-attached-views-may-not-be-recycled-since-support-lib-25-0-0)

I have no knowledge of this crash from where it is occurring. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am neither using "android:animateLayoutChanges="true"

Basically  i had tried to merge these two different GitHub project,

[rv-adapter-states](https://github.com/rockerhieu/rv-adapter-states)

[rv-adapter-endless](https://github.com/rockerhieu/rv-adapter-endless)

My files links are as follows from pastbin,

[Row Layout](http://pastebin.com/Y4kf8Sxm)

[Code of recyclerview](http://pastebin.com/6bT3KbKP)

[My Adapter merge from two diffrent adapter of rv](http://pastebin.com/9GwSGe50)

[Main adapter](http://pastebin.com/WrVrrKGi)

Comment: post your recyclerview and adapter code

Comment: @Divyesh, i had added the code

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @TrevorFranklin, no

Comment: I would recommend to avoid using same view in the `onCreateViewHolder`. You always return same view, that may be already attached to parent:
`return new SimpleViewHolder(vLoadingView);` If you look into the `getPendingView` in the `rv-adapter-endless` it always inflates new view to avoid this issue.

Comment: Line number 69 of your recycler view code uncomment the code aOrdersAdapter.setHasStableIds(true); and try again.

Comment: @SabinBajracharya, it will not work i had already checked it.

Comment: @AlexM, i will try it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I don't know why is happening.

I solved it removing the `android:animateLayoutChanges` on the recyclerview and to animate the recyclerview I have added: 
`recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());`

Take an account to add the method `public long getItemId(int position)` and set `setHasStableIds(true)` if you want animate it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `layoutManager.setItemPrefetchEnabled(false);`? It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because of the incorrect implementing of this method `public long getItemId(int position)` (overrided from `RecyclerView.Adapter` method).

The old code will get two different ids for the same item (in my case it is the footer item), after fixing the implementation the issue has gone.